# StackOverflowError in UncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, android, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I have implemented a uncaught exception handler to catch uncaught exceptions. But some time or in some devices this handler failed with `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Here is logcat of exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:31)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:459)
at com.example.src.CustomExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CustomExceptionHandler.java:36)
at com.example.src.CustomExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CustomExceptionHandler.java:41)
at com.example.src.CustomExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(CustomExceptionHandler.java:41)
```

And the line that cause error `defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);` according to stacktrace.

And full code is:

```
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import android.util.Log;

class CustomExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

protected CustomExceptionHandler() {
    try
    {
        this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
    }
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    try
    {
        String stacktrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);

        SendStackTraceToServer sendStackTraceToServer = new SendStackTraceToServer();
        sendStackTraceToServer.startThreadToSendRequest(stacktrace);

        defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e); // this line cause stackoverflow error.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ex);
    }
}

protected static void setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()
{
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler());
}
}
```

Help me solve this issue. Because I am not able to reproduce this issue (or I don't know how to reproduce this issue).

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.StackOverflowError is Error not Exception

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

You can catch Throwable if you need to catch all "throwable"

Comment: Anyway it is bad idea to catch it

Comment: OK. Do you have any idea why "UncaughtExceptionHandler" cause stackoverflow error at line  defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);. What is the reason of application recurses too deeply.

Answer (score 0):

defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e); invokes defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e); invokes defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e); ... and in the end you get StackOverflowError.

May be I am not right, but I think your code is complex.

I recommend use Handler like this:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        String stacktrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        SendStackTraceToServer sendStackTraceToServer = new SendStackTraceToServer();
        sendStackTraceToServer.startThreadToSendRequest(stacktrace);
    }
});
```

Comment: If I removed "defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);" from function then my app hanged when any uncaught exception occur. Any idea?

Comment: @DevK I don't understand your question. What you want to do?